# How to create secured page that limits access to users with the correct permissions?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

For a Drupal 7 site, I need to create a secured page with a list (view) of documents(.pdf's).  There will be one page with a list of documents (a view of pdf's).  To get to that page and be able to download any of the .pdf's, the user must be logged in with their own unique username/password.  So what I believe needs to be done is the following.

1. Set up a page with a view of the documents (can do).
2. Make sure the docs (pdf's) can't be viewed with a direct URL (I think private file)
3. **Prevent access to the page by non-logged in users. (no idea. help!)**
4. **Create a menu item for the page that only displays when the user is logged in. (no idea. help!)**
5. Define permissions for accessing the page and add the permissions to specific roles. (I think I can do)

Can anyone provide info on how to do this?  Is there a module for this functionality?

thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use content_access module to do this. You will be able to restrict access to any content (you list page) by role.

If you create a link to this page in the main/secondary nav (for example) then this link should only appear to a user that has the appropriate permissions (as defined in the role).

LF

Answer (score 1):

create some permissions and assign that to particular user then in your hook_meny you can use user_acccess function to check that whether the logged in user has that permisiion or not and according to that return true or false.

```
if(user_access(YOUR_PERMISSION_HERE)) {
    return TRUE;
  }
else {
return FALSE
}
```

You can also write your sql query inside that. You can put this code in your function and call that function in your access callback for that particular form menu definition